# How to Create new Database from Existing Database in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I need to create new database from existing database. I mean to say i have some "xyz" database in the sql server now i need to create new database and i want to import all the table structure and tables data and stored procedures and views and functions from the existing database("xyz") to newly created database. I want to do this entire process using stored procedure.

Comment: The conventional way would be to use mysqldump; create the new DB, and then use the following from the commandline: `mysqldump -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] [old_DB_name] | mysql -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] [new_DB_name]`. Does it _have_ to be in a stored procedure?

Comment: remember to include `--routines` for the `mysqldump` command if you want to export stored procedures as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP script.

executable file example01.php code as follows:

```
     <?php
// connection SQL server database
$conn=mssql_connect("localhost","sa","");        //sqlserver name, name,password
mssql_select_db("table_book",$conn);             //table_book is sqlserver database name
//connection mysql database
$id=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");    //localhost,user name:root,password:root
mysql_select_db("shop_book",$id);                //shop_book is mysql database
//select all books table content in sqlserver
$ms_query=mssql_query("select * from book",$conn);
//foreach output book table content
while($msrow=mssql_fetch_array($ms_query)){
$name=$msrow[name];                              //set variable
$author=$msrow[author];
$bookconcern=$msrow[bookconcern];
//add data mysql database
$query=mysql_query("insert into book(name,author,bookconcern)
values('$name','$author','$bookconcern')",$id);   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the database that is required to create a new database. You have to copy or clone the database names and its structures to another database with newest name to be provided. Hope it will help u....